# deg functions and maps

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

For any map $f$ between curves $C_1$ and $C_2$, one defines $\mathrm{deg}(f) = [K(C_1) : f^*K(C_2)]$ as given in *"The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves"* by Silverman. 
For algebraic functions on elliptic curves it is possible to define the degree as the number of poles (with multiplicities). Why is this the same? Can you give a reference?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that these are exactly the same, rather, the second is an instance of the first. A meromorphic function on an elliptic curve $C$ defines a morphism $f:C\to\mathbb P^1,$ and the number of poles is by definition the number of points in the fibre over $\infty$ (with multiplicities). The degree $\deg(f)$ is in general the number of (distinct) points in a general fibre of $f,$ which equals the number of poles, as long as we count with multiplicity. So it stands to reason that the two definition are the same.

A reference is section II.2 of Silverman (specifically, Example 2.2 and Proposition 2.6 should be helpful).